# Issue when trying to show Video in WebView

Tags: android, webview

Hello everybody

I'm trying to show in a WebView a video from url, it is streaming and this is an example of the Url:

```
https://rapidresponse-us-oem-relay11.mios.com/relay/relay/relay/device/36050280/session/0144E086FE4180BB14CFA858AE7FE05757ED73/port_3480/data_request?id=serve_stream&cam=12&stream=29&res=low
```

I already did the IOS application and it works fine, so I know that the url don't have any problem.

I'm trying to show the video in the WebView with the following code:

```
if(message.getMessageType() == 0) {
            webView_camera.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView_camera.loadUrl(cameraUrl);

        }
```

I tried to use this

```
webView_camera.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

But it doesn't work either

When the application run only show int the webview the icon of failure to load an image.

I'm pretty new with this so any help will be appreciated it

**UPDATE**

This is the Logs that I get from android:

```
11-11 09:32:25.268 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 46.0.2490.76 (code 249007600)
11-11 09:32:25.294 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/cr.library_loader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 2963-2965)
11-11 09:32:25.294 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "46.0.2490.76", actual native library version number "46.0.2490.76"
11-11 09:32:25.306 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b23e619}
11-11 09:32:25.307 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/cr.library_loader: Expected native library version number "46.0.2490.76", actual native library version number "46.0.2490.76"
11-11 09:32:25.309 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(118)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-11 09:32:25.329 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/cr.BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
11-11 09:32:25.336 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
11-11 09:32:25.417 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/chromium: [ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(258)] Failed to init browser shader disk cache.
11-11 09:32:25.445 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-11 09:32:25.449 8316-8774/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/cr.media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
11-11 09:32:25.471 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
11-11 09:32:25.472 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
11-11 09:32:25.526 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
11-11 09:32:25.526 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
11-11 09:32:25.554 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
11-11 09:32:25.562 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
11-11 09:32:30.958 8316-8316/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster W/cr.BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8316
11-11 09:33:18.836 8316-8398/com.realstatediary.jperera.rapidsentrymaster D/PULLBACK: Executing background pull from server
```

Comment: The link you provided is not working on Google Chrome browser, are you sure that is the url you are using on the iOS app?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure but it is not working because the token expire but this is the structure of the url and works fine

Comment: I tested again, and in the IOS application I'm loading exactly the same url structure in to a UIWebView with the method loadRequest and works fine

Comment: Did you try enabling Javascript? webView_camera.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Thank you @mmark yes, i did that test but it doesn't work neither. I don't find a way to get it work

Comment: Hello, I really need some help with this issue, please any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did!

This the solution:

```
if(message.getMessageType() == 0) {
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.append("<html>");
            html.append("<head>");
            html.append("</head>");
            html.append("<body>");
            html.append("<div id ='main'><img class=\"video_player_frame\"src=\""+cameraUrl+" style=\"top: 0px; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;\"></div>");
            html.append("</body>");
            html.append("</html>");
            webView_camera.loadData(html.toString(),"text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
```